# Convert multiple SQL columns in a row to JSON and update to a column in the same row

Tags: sql, json

I'm trying to serialize multiple columns in a row to JSON and update it to a column in the same row:

```
UPDATE  dbo.ItemSpecification
SET ItemCameraData = (SELECT CameraFocalLengthMin, CameraFocalLengthMax, CameraHousingType, CameraMountType, CameraResolutionHorizontal, CameraResolutionVertical, CameraType FROM dbo.ItemSpecification
WHERE Id = Id
FOR JSON AUTO)
```

The select statment is ignoring the "Where Id = Id" and trying to serialize the whole table into each row instead of just the columns from the single row it's updating.

How do I specify in the select statement to only serialize the columns in the single row it's updating and not the entire table?

**UPDATE:**

here it is with the answer applied.
Azure SQL wants to alias the table in the FROM statement

```
UPDATE  dbo.ItemSpecification
SET ItemCameraData = (SELECT CameraFocalLengthMin, CameraFocalLengthMax, CameraHousingType, CameraMountType, CameraResolutionHorizontal, CameraResolutionVertical, CameraType FROM dbo.ItemSpecification
WHERE Id = outer_stmt.Id
FOR JSON AUTO)
FROM dbo.ItemSpecification outer_stmt
```

Comment: Yes, the inner query will only use its own filters, currently none; it won't go out and use those of the outer query.

Comment: You need to make it a correlated subquery. Or use a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what database you're using, so my syntax may be slightly off, but the concept should match.

It's unlikely your inner statement knows what you're trying to do with `Id = Id`. You need to reference the outer table, or you're going to get the equivalent of `1 = 1`. Since this is the same table, I've aliased the outer table so it can then be referenced in the inner select statement.

```sql
UPDATE  dbo.ItemSpecification as outer_stmt
SET ItemCameraData = (
  SELECT 
    CameraFocalLengthMin, CameraFocalLengthMax, CameraHousingType
    , CameraMountType, CameraResolutionHorizontal, CameraResolutionVertical
    , CameraType 
  FROM dbo.ItemSpecification
  WHERE 
    Id = outer_stmt.Id
  FOR JSON AUTO
)
```

Comment: It's Microsoft Azure SQL. It doesn't like the "as outer_stmt" part...

Comment: I just had to remove the "as outer_stmt" and add "FROM dbo.ItemSpecification outer_stmt" to alias the outer table in Azure SQL. thanks!